How to query a clickhouse table for a given timestamp in python?
Using clickhouse-connect I am querying a table to get a timestamp:
import clickhouse_connect

client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(
    host=CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_HOSTNAME, 
    username=CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_USER, 
    password=CLICKHOUSE_CLOUD_PASSWORD
)
q0 = "SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM mydb.mytable"
r0 = list(client.query(q).named_results())
print(r0)

"""
Getting the below results:
[{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 1, 0, 0, 25, 26208, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 1, 0, 0, 25, 27033, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 1, 0, 0, 25, 27597, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)}]
"""

Now I want to query the DB to get all the data for the first timestamp here:
dtt = r0[0]['timestamp']

parameters = {"v1":dtt, "query_tz":"UTC"}
# also tried: parameters = {"v1":dtt, "query_tz":"UTC"}
# also tried: parameters = {"v1":dtt.astimezone(pytz.utc), "query_tz":"UTC"}
# also tried: parameters = {"v1":dtt.astimezone(pytz.utc)}

q1 = "SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable WHERE timestamp = {v1:DateTime}"
r1 = client.query(qq, parameters=parameters)
print(list(r1.named_results()))

# result is always empty: []

But i cannot get the row, and I tried different versions of the timestamp.
The type of the timestamp column in the table is DateTime64(6)
Useful for reproduction:

python: 3.11
clickhouse-connect: 0.7.18
OS: Windows


hi moonrekter - it's a little difficult to answer given what we see here. I'd suggest posting your table definition also (SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable) so we can see the data type of the timestamp column. I'm guessing that the structure of the query for the parameters variable does not match the data type of the timestamp column in ClickHouse, and thus gets no results

Added the type to the question. It's DateTime64(6)

Actually, that won't work.  clickhouse_connect only formats the V1 to seconds, so if the timestamp in your column has milliseconds, the WHERE clause will not be satisfied.
Basically DateTime64 parameter binding isn't supported in clickhouse_connect.  Please open a Github issue here:  https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-connect/issues

Is there a way to go around it in the meantime? Without using parameters maybe

I think you can just send a "string formatted" DateTime64(6) like so:
WHERE timestamp = '2019-01-01 03:00:00.123456'
